# Apache HttpClientBuilder - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I get `IllegalArgumentException` when trying to build Apache HttpClient instance wit HttpClientBuilder:

```
private CloseableHttpClient delegate;

public DigestClient(String user, String pass) {
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass);

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    delegate = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();
}
```

what I get is:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Item may not be null
        at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:48)
        at org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder.register(RegistryBuilder.java:58)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:727)
        at com.example.app.data.net.DigestClient.<init>(DigestClient.java:51)
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Here's my gradle with HttpClient's version:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading `httpclient-android` version fixed it for me:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here:

> http://javacave.blogspot.com/2014/08/androidapache-httpclient.html

For those who don't know Chinese:

I had to do:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
```

and then

```
delegate = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
```

At least it doesn't crash this way.

Comment: Thank you for providing this fix. The httpclient 4.3 interface problems cause some really weird dependencies in Gradle. Had to override my HttpClientBuilder:
<br/>
<!-- language: lang-java -->
<code>
public class CustomBuilder extends HttpClientBuilder {
    @Override
    public CloseableHttpClient build() {
        setUserAgent(AndroidSendGridApi.USER_AGENT);
        useSystemProperties();
        setSslcontext(SSLContexts.createSystemDefault());
        return super.build();
    }
}
</code>

Answer (score 0):

```
private CloseableHttpClient delegate;

public DigestClient(String user, String pass) {
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, pass);

    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    delegate = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.